# Problem of Conditional Probability

Tags: probability

I am learning Probability from Sheldon Ross book.

One of the problems starts by giving the probability $P_N$ that there are no matches when $N$ people select from among their own $N$ hats as 
$$P_N=\sum_{i=0}^{N}{\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}}$$
The excerpt from solution is as follows:

1. Let us consider a particular set of $k$ people.
2. Let $E$ be the event that everyone in this set has a match.
3. Let $G$ be the event that none of the other $N-n$ people have a match.
4. Given that everyone in the set of k has a match, the other $N − k$ people will be randomly choosing among their own $N − k$ hats, so the probability that none of them has a match is equal to the probability of no matches in a problem having $N − k$ people choosing among their own $N − k$ hats.
5. Therefore,
   $$P(G|E)=P_{N-k}=\sum_{i=0}^{N-k}{\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}}$$

However I dont understand how it is $P(G|E)$. It should be $P(G)$, as the assumption done in point 3.

Comment: But part 4 is talking exactly about $G|E$.

Comment: ok then I did not understood 4th point itself. How is 
(Given that everyone in the set of k has a match, the other N−k people will be randomly choosing among their own N−k hats, so the probability that none of them has a match) **=** (the probability of no matches in a problem having N−k people choosing among their own N−k hats)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ok then I did not understood 4th point itself. How is (Given that everyone in the set of k has a match, the other N−k people will be randomly choosing among their own N−k hats, so the probability that none of them has a match) = (the probability of no matches in a problem having N−k people choosing among their own N−k hats)

We have arbitrarily divided $N$ people into two clusters, call them $A,B$.  If $A$ is of size $k$, then $B$ will be of size $N-k$.

Event $E$ is the event that everyone in cluster $A$ has their own hat.   If this happens then where are all the hats belonging to people in cluster $B$?   No-one in cluster $A$ will have any of them if everyone in cluster $A$ has their own hat, so...

Event $G$ is the event that no one in cluster $B$ has their own hat.

Thus the probability $P(G\mid E)$ is the (conditional) probability that no-one in cluster $B$ has their own hat, *given that* all the hats in cluster $B$ belong to *someone* in that cluster (since everyone in cluster $A$ has their own hat).   Thus it is the probability that $N-k$ people and their own $N-k$ hats will be mismatched.

Comment: It sounds like "let A be the cluster of ***all*** people who has their own hat". However this is not the case, right? A is just the cluster of people. And now it happens that all of people in A has their own hat. That does not necessarily mean that none of people in B have their own hat. 

Say A = {1,2}, B = {3,4,5,6}. 
1 and 2 have their own hat. But it is not necessary that none of 3,4,5, and 6 can have their own hat? For example, 3 and 4 can have their own hat. 5 can have 6's hat and 6 can have 5's hat. Or is it indeed like "let A be the cluster of ***all*** people who has their own hat"...

Comment: ...or is it like $G$ is independent of $E$, that is occurrence of $E$ does not change the probability of $G$, thus $P(G|E) = P(G)$?

Comment: $G$ is *not* independent of $E$.  The probability that none of the $N-k$ people (group B) find their own hats is clearly quite different on condition that some of the $k$ people (group A) *don't* all have their own hat; as group A then *could* have some of group B's hats. @Mahesha999

Comment: What the book seems to be building up to is finding the probability that exactly $k$ of $N$ people find their own hats.

Comment: I think I am getting with what you explained above, Also read the explanation again. Just want to confirm. $G$ is *the event that none of the other N people have a match*, while $G|E$ is *the event that there are no matches when N people select **from among their own N hats***. Is this difference if I have to put it verbally? So that "*from among their own N hats*" is missing from $G$ and gets considered in $G|E$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's the essence of it. @Mahesha999